# specific status on consecutive days

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table `ATT` which has `EMP_ID`,`ATT_DATE`,`ATT_STATUS` with `ATT_STATUS` with different values 1-Present,2-Absent,3-Weekly-off. I want to find out those `EMP_ID`'s which have status 2 consecutively for 10 days in a given date range.

Please help

Comment: is it updated daily or is should it display if there are values 10 times

Comment: table schema from `show create table att`?

Comment: Its a attendance table which is populated every day. I want to generate a report where I can see between specific dates, say in a month, how many employees are there who have been absent for consecutive 10 days and more.

Comment: How do you want to handle weekends then? They work in the weekends too?

Comment: you might want to write a procedure for this.

Comment: Yeah... they are round the clock employees, so it doesnt matter whether it is what day of the week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with this:

```
SELECT EMP_ID FROM (
SELECT
IF((@prevDate!=(q.ATT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)) OR (@prevEmp!=q.EMP_ID) OR (q.ATT_STATUS != 2), @rownum:=@rownum+1, @rownum:=@rownum) AS rownumber, @prevDate:=q.ATT_DATE, @prevEmp:=q.EMP_ID, q.*
FROM (
SELECT
EMP_ID
, ATT_DATE
, ATT_STATUS
FROM
org_tb_dailyattendance, (SELECT @rownum:=0, @prevDate:='', @prevEmp:=0) vars
WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-15'
ORDER BY EMP_ID, ATT_DATE, ATT_STATUS
) q
) sq
GROUP BY EMP_ID, rownumber
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 10
```

The logic is, to first sort the table by employee id and the dates. Then introduce a rownumber which increases only if

- the days are not consecutive or
- the employee id is not the previous one or
- the status is not 2

Then I just grouped by this rownumber and counted if there are 10 rows in each group. That should be the ones who were absent for 10 days or more.

Comment: Checked this one.. but giving a syntax error.. not able to find what it is.. can you plz let me know what it can be

Comment: How about posting the error message? You replaced startdate and enddate I hope.

Comment: SELECT EMP_ID FROM (
SELECT
IF(prevDate!=q.ATT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY OR prevEmp!=q.EMP_ID OR q.ATT_STATUS != 2, rownum:=rownum+1) AS rownumber, 
prevDate:=q.ATT_DATE, prevEmp:=q.EMP_ID, q.*
FROM (
SELECT
EMP_ID
, ATT_DATE
, ATT_STATUS
FROM
org_tb_dailyattendance, (SELECT rownum:=0, prevDate:='', prevEmp:=0) vars
WHERE ATT_DATE BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-02-05'
ORDER BY EMP_ID, ATT_DATE
) q
) sq
GROUP BY rownumber
HAVING COUNT(*) > 10 - I have removed @ in this reply as it is not allowing me to put..

Comment: Yes, but what about the error message? Where's the syntax error exactly.

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS rownumber,  prevDate:=q.ATT_DATE, prevEmp:=q.EMP_ID, q.* FROM ( SELECT EM' at line 1

Comment: Yes, like I said, I updated the query. Syntax error should be corrected. Please have a try again.

Comment: Hey Sorry I had not seen your update.. Yes it is working.. but instead of q.ATT_STATUS != 2 I have made q.ATT_STATUS = 2.. Thanks Tom.. It was really a gr8 help

Comment: @user2110341 Glad to hear that. The usual way to say thanks here is to accept the answer and/or upvote. This way others also see, that it's solved and don't waste time. :)

Comment: Sorry new to this.. You mean to say I should paste the query here?

Comment: No, I meant you could click the green check left to my answer and or the arrow pointing upwards :)

Comment: I am sorry to open this again. It is giving emp_ids which are even having consecutive status=2 for 6 days also !!! Any idea where is it going wrong ? Please suggest

Comment: One more update - It is showing emp_ids which are even having att_status=2 for 2 consecutive days... I guess the count >=10 isn't being cosidered...

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Preferably on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: It seems it is considering the total att_status between those dates and not consecutive. Even if the total status=2>=10, it is showing output for those emp_id, be it consecutive or not.

Comment: Like I said, please provide sample data. It's actually a bit hard to understand your question and even harder to write queries without the ability to play around.

Comment: Please try this on sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea1a1/4            If you see I have made a check for att_status=5 and it gives output 1787 emp_id. But if you see, 1787 doesnt have att_status=5 for 10 consecutive days. Please suggest

Comment: @user2110341 Okay, corrected it. Please try again with updated query. Only Emp_ID 1790 should be returned, right? Only one who has status 2 for more than 10 days. I'll have a look again tomorrow, gotta go now.

Comment: @user2110341 So, any feedback? Does it give you the desired result?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this

```
SELECT EMP_ID count(*) as consecutive_count min(ATT_DATE)
FROM (SELECT * FROM ATT ORDER BY EMP_ID) 
GROUP BY EMP_ID, ATT_DATE
WHERE ATT_STATUS = 2
HAVING consecutive_count > 10
```

Comment: I want to specify a date range and find out those employee ids which are marked 2 as att_status consecutively for x number of days in the date range specified

Comment: then include this into the above WHERE clause 
WHERE ATT_STATUS = 2 & ATT_DATE BETWEEN <your_start_date> AND <your_end_date>

Comment: This is totally wrong, there are several syntax errors, the `order by` will have no effect and this would only work if the user enters a date range of 10 days, not more. Then the `> 10` should be `>= 10`. Otherwise you can't guarantee, that the employee had status 10 **consecutively**!